# Find repeated numbered files

Tags: bash, script, find

I have a bunch of files with names like this

```
file_1_v4_sdk.x
file_2_v1_3kl.x
file_3_v1_39f.x
file_3_v2_df0.x
file_4_v4_f33.x
file_4_v1_fks.x
file_4_v5_skd.x
file_5_v2_9ks.x
file_6_v4_911.x
file_7_v2_3jd.x
file_8_v1_9pc.x
file_8_v4_gpq.x
```

So,there are several versions of some of the files, but such versions don't have an order. I want to find those files that have several versions and leave just one version in the directory and move the other versions into another directory. I don't have a clue about how to do this. I only know how to iterate over lists, but in this case there is no order.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: This shouldn't be terrible to do if you understand BASH and grep. I can make you some sample code, i just need to know what version of each file you want to keep - I assume you want the highest version of each file to stay and move the others out?

Comment: yes the, highest version would be ok and move the others to another directory

Comment: _"highest version would be ok"_  Just "OK"?  Before any volunteer here makes the effort to write code, explain what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU sort and bash:

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/your/files
GLOBIGNORE="$(printf "%s\n" file_* | sort -t _ -k2,3r | sort -t _ -k2,2 -u | tr '\n' :)"
mv file_* /path/to/dir/to/save/old/versions
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Comment: yes this worked perfectly , thanks a lot, now i will find out how it works, Thanks